# VBA: Command Prompt response not showing in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shell, memory, command-prompt

Im trying to find my Available Physical Memory through VBA. my goal is to run the systeminfo |find “Available Physical Memory” command in VBA and see the results. for some reason this is not working but is working with other commands ive tried. My initial thought is that the way i have the code written, it is not waiting on the command prompt to finish. any thoughts or help? thank you

```
Sub MemoryCheck()
Dim availableMem As String
    availableMem = ExecShellCmd("systeminfo |find ""Available Physical Memory""")
    Debug.Print "availableMem: "; availableMem
End Sub

Public Function ExecShellCmd(FuncExec As String) As String
    Dim wsh As Object, wshOut As Object, sShellOut As String, sShellOutline As String
    
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
    Set wshOut = wsh.exec(FuncExec).stdout
    
    While Not wshOut.AtEndOfStream
        sShellOutline = wshOut.ReadLine
        If sShellOutline <> "" Then
            sShellOut = sShellOut & sShellOutline & vbCrLf
        End If
    Wend
    
    ExecShellCmd = sShellOut
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub MemoryCheck()
    Dim availableMem As String
    availableMem = ExecShellCmd("systeminfo |find ""Available Physical Memory""")
    Debug.Print "availableMem: "; availableMem
End Sub

Public Function ExecShellCmd(FuncExec As String) As String
    ExecShellCmd = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
                    .exec("cmd.exe /c " & FuncExec).stdout.readall
End Function
```